# Flask app: Post json to server for use in a different REST API

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, flask

I have a Flask app with some vanilla Javascript (I don't know JQuery). It does the following:
(1) The user enters some data in an HTML table. (2) The data is then parsed to JSON. (3) I want to post the JSON file to the server. (4) From the server, the JSON object is posted to a different REST API for further use.

Steps 1, 2 and 4 work (I can `console.log` the JSON object), but I'm at a loss how to post a JSON object from client to server. The option I keep seeing is to move the table between  tags and then post the table via `request.form`. I'm happy to do that but it seems clunky compared to parsing JSON on the client side and posting a clean object to the server that can be used immediately by the third-party REST API. What am I missing here?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <body>
      <button id="click">Click</button>
      <table id="myTable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>001</td>
    <td>Trousers</td>
    <td>9.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>002</td>
    <td>Shirt</td>
    <td>19.99</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>003</td>
    <td>Shoes</td>
    <td>49.99</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>


    </body>

    <script>
      const btn = document.getElementById("click");
      btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        tableToJson(table);
      })
      
    let table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    function tableToJson(table) {
    var data = [];

    // first row needs to be headers
    var headers = [];
    for (var i=0; i<table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
        headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi,'');
    }

    // go through cells
    for (var i=1; i<table.rows.length; i++) {

        var tableRow = table.rows[i];
        var rowData = {};

        for (var j=0; j<tableRow.cells.length; j++) {

            rowData[ headers[j] ] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;

        }

        data.push(rowData);
    }       
    console.log(data);
    
    return data;
}
    </script>
    </html>
```

````
app = Flask(__name__) # Create an Instance

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) # Route the Function and allow Requests
def main(): # Run the function
    if request.method == 'POST': # Identify Request Method
        value = request.form['input'] # Gather the Post Request
        return value
    if request.method == 'GET': # Identify Request Method
        return render_template('index.html')

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True) # Run the Application (in debug mode)```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to send the data.
In the following example, the data is converted into a JSON-compliant character string and sent to the server via POST.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="click">Click</button>
    <table id="my-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>001</td>
          <td>Trousers</td>
          <td>9.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>002</td>
          <td>Shirt</td>
          <td>19.99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>003</td>
          <td>Shoes</td>
          <td>49.99</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (() => {
        const tableToJSON = (tableElem) => {
          const tableRows = Array.from(tableElem.rows);
          const tableHead = Array.from(tableRows[0].cells).map(cell => {
            return cell.innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'_')
          });
          return tableRows.slice(1).map(row => {
            const rowData = {}
            Array.from(row.cells).forEach((cell, i) => {
              return rowData[tableHead[i]] = cell.innerHTML;
            });
            return rowData;
          });
        };

        const btnElem = document.getElementById('click');
        btnElem.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
          const tableElem = document.getElementById('my-table');
          const tableData = tableToJSON(tableElem);

          // Post JSON data to the server.
          const url = '/data';
          fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(tableData)
          }).then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data));
        });
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you can request and process the data on the server using [`request.get_json()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request.get_json). The response from the server is a simple JSON object that was converted with [jsonify](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify).

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret here'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/data', methods=['POST']) 
def data(): 
    data = request.get_json()
    print(data)
    return jsonify(success=True)
```

Comment: I'm afraid this does not work in my setup (I use replit). To run it I added `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)` to main.py. index.html is loaded, but neither the console.log nor the print statements are executed, so I guess no data is posted to the server?

Comment: @vauss Sorry, I changed my answer slightly.
If your server is running on port 8080 you would have to adjust the url to which it is sent. I have now reduced the url to the path. This is how it should work in your setup.